# How to store in SVN a Eclipse C Project

Tags: eclipse, project

I would like to know how to store in SVN a Eclipse Neon C Project, so that it can be worked in another system.

I have committed the files .project .cproject and the directory .settings

But when, on another system, I do:

File | Open Projects from File System | ...

I don't get a project on Eclipse workspace.

I also tried the Export / Import options with no success.

Could someone tell me what files should be saved and what procedures to execute?

thanks

Comment: I am pretty sure there is a bunch of SVN plugins for Eclipse.

Comment: is it possible to do it without a plugin? I would prefer to have full control... :)

Comment: I removed the C tag.

Comment: Sharing the `.project`, `.cproject` files and the `.settings` folder should be sufficient to be able to import the project on another system. This should also work with the old Eclipse version you have. Can you please tell exactly what happens when opening/importing the project on another system?

Comment: That's what I thought! But when I import the project by using the Import dialog box and give the Directory where .project .cproject and .settings are only the source files in the directory are imported! Also the compiler settings (like include directories, optimisation options) are not set...